# How to label two vertices on a semicircle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I would like to draw a semicircle with dashed line style and label two vertices on the semicircle. I used the following code, but it's strange that these two vertices don't fall on the semicircle. I don't know why.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Draw a dashed semicircle
  %\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \draw [dashed](0,0) arc (0:180:1cm);
  % Define angles for the vertices
  \def\angleA{60}
  \def\angleB{\angleA - 60}

  % Mark two adjacent vertices on the semicircle using nodes
  \node[circle, fill, inner sep=1.5pt, label=left:A] (A) at (\angleA:1cm) {};
  \node[circle, fill, inner sep=1.5pt, label=left:B] (B) at (\angleB:1cm) {};

  % Draw an edge on the semicircle between A and B
  \draw (A) arc (\angleA:\angleB:1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It seems that the center of this semicircle is not (0,0).

The following output is what I wanted.

[image]

Comment: Your dashed arc starts at (0,0) and has center at (-1,0). On the other hand the other arc (and the nodes A,B are placed on it) ends at B(1,0) and has center at (0,0). Pace both centers at the same point. For example, change: `\draw [dashed](1,0) arc (0:180:1cm);`

Comment: Thank you, I misunderstood that arc was drawn with the center at (0,0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your problem is solved by comment, just an off-topic suggestion. I would draw your image on the following way:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3 mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=1.5pt, 
              label= #1, node contents={}},
every label/.append style = {inner sep=1pt}
                    ]
\draw [dashed]  (1,0) arc (0:180:1cm);
\draw   (1,0) node[dot=right:B] arc [start angle=0, 
                                     delta angle=60, 
                                     radius=1] node[dot=60:A];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: isn't node missing? node[dot=60:A]

Comment: @pascal974, you are right! I was lost somewhere :-( corrected now.